# API gateway different authenticaton mechanism for different endpoints

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

I have a serverless application built with node js. There are 4 lamdas in my serverless.yaml file. I know API gateway authentication will be applied to all of its endpoints if I do it.
But is there any way I can secure 2 APIs with cognito authentication and other 2 using API-Kay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do this and it is a very common pattern.

If you are using console, you will find all the authorizers that are configured for the API under a dropdown, if you go into the Method Request for the resource

[image]

If you are developing via SAM, you can find more about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-controlling-access-to-apis.html).

For me personally, generally using facing API like those to be used via dashboards on browsers are secured via Cognito Authorizers and API exposed for integrations in other systems (like microservices) are exposed via custom Lambda Authorizers.